# PHP Variable Containing HTML as String - Needed to be converted to Image or PDF - Emailing The Response

Tags: php, html, image, pdf, html-email

I am Sending email form php code and my email message body is HTML
once the email is sent background image is not displaying in outlook desktop app, but its working fine in Outlook Web mail, how to make it visible in desktop outlook application

due to which I am am thinking of converting email body to a pdf or image so that i can add it as message body

can anyone please guide me to do it

```
$emailBody='<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
#textDiv{
background-image: url("appreciation-'.$imageId.'.jpg");background-repeat: no-repeat;width:595px;height: 842px;color: white;float: center;
}
#p1{
padding-top: 420px;padding-left: 50px;width: 500px;font-size: large;
}
#p2{
padding-top: 30px;padding-left: 50px;width: 500px;font-size: 25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center> 
<div id="textDiv"  align="center" style="font-family: cursive; text-align:center;">
    <p id="p1">Hi '.$actReciverName.', you have received Kudos from '.$senderName.' </p>
    <p id="p2"><i><u>"'.$comment.'"</u></i></p> 
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>'
```

thanks in advance for your Support

Comment: dompdf will help you out with this issue. Here is link `https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf` . and instead of adding in the body. you can attach `pdf` in `mail attachment`. The right way is send `pdf or images` over the mail is `mail attachment`

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best practice to add images as background in email body/templates, if wanted, here some **hacks** for IE and Outlook since those email readers are based on MS Word it's necessary to add some XML and special tags inside IE comments into HTML code.

Example:

```html
<div style="background-color:#7bceeb;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png">

        ... your content here ...

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**NOTE** For email, use `<table>` as much as you can instead `<div>`

Use as reference: https://backgrounds.cm/